# not able to post images through rest framework django but says status code 200

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have everything set up but when I starts posting into DRF through post function with image it shows status code 200 but does not return dynamic id of object and there is no new object in database, but when I remove imagefield from models and try to post  it does not give me error and returns id of posted object..

models.py

```
 class Accounts(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(default='default.png')

    def __str__(self):
       return f'Account object'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Accounts


class Accountserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = Accounts
       fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_data(request):
   serializer = Accountserializers(data=request.data)
   if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

     return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is the code as i said when i post something it says status code 200 and does not return dynamic id.. pls help me find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send errors back if there is an error. Like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_data(request):
   serializer = Accountserializers(data=request.data)
   # or use serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
   if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
   else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status_code=status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

More information can be found in [DRF serializer validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) documentation.